# React Native- Highlight item from a flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this function to highlight an item from a flatlist. It does highlight it, when pressed but once pressed again does not unselected the value and it doesn't save it to the state. I;m using React hooks to manage state. Data is an array of objects. I just want to add ability to unselect a value in this function.

```js
const [selected, setSelect] = useState(Data);
  
const presshandler = (id) => {
  setSelect((prev) => {
    return prev.map((item) => {
      if (item.id !== id) return item;
      return {
        ...item,
        selectedClass: item.id ? styles.selected : null,
      };
    });
  });
};]]

  <List
    source={selected}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    extraData={setSelect}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => presshandler(item.id)}
      >
        <View>
          <ListDetails
            item={item}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition will fix this `item.selectedClass ? null : styles.selected`

```
const presshandler = (id) => {
  setSelect((prev) => {
    return prev.map((item) => {
      if (item.id !== id) return item;
      return {
        ...item,
        selectedClass: item.selectedClass ? null : styles.selected,
      };
    });
  });
};]]
```